# what in kafka DefaultRecord value field

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Recently, I review the kafka code and test. I found a strange case:
I print the bytebuffer on the entry of SocketServer processCompletedReceives, as well as print the value on the point of Log sotre as follows:
the entry of SocketServer

```
  private def processCompletedReceives() {
selector.completedReceives.asScala.foreach { receive =>
  try {
    openOrClosingChannel(receive.source) match {
      case Some(channel) =>
        val header = RequestHeader.parse(receive.payload)
        val connectionId = receive.source
        val context = new RequestContext(header, connectionId, channel.socketAddress,
          channel.principal, listenerName, securityProtocol)
        val req = new RequestChannel.Request(processor = id, context = context,
          startTimeNanos = time.nanoseconds, memoryPool, receive.payload, requestChannel.metrics)

        if(header.apiKey() == ApiKeys.PRODUCE){
          LogHelper.log("produce request: %v" + java.util.Arrays.toString(receive.payload.array()))
        }
```

...

the point of Log

```
validRecords.records().asScala.foreach { record =>
    LogHelper.log("buffer info: value " + java.util.Arrays.toString(record.value().array()))
}
```

but, the result of print is different. and record.value() is not what I passed in client value like this:

```
    public void run() {
    int messageNo = 1;
    while (true) {
        String messageStr = "Message_" + messageNo;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (isAsync) { // Send asynchronously
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic,
                messageNo,
                messageStr), new DemoCallBack(startTime, messageNo, messageStr));
        } else { // Send synchronously
            try {
                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic,
                    messageNo,
                    messageStr)).get();
                System.out.println("Sent message: (" + messageNo + ", " + messageStr + ")");
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ++messageNo;
    }
}
```

the print result is not the not `String messageStr = "Message_" + messageNo;`
so what happend in the case.

Comment: What actually your application is printing?

Comment: The issue might be with Serializer and Deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

done.  I write the code as follows:

```
public class KVExtractor {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KVExtractor.class);

    public static Map.Entry<byte[], byte[]> extract(Record record) {
        if (record.hasKey() && record.hasValue()) {
            byte[] key = new byte[record.key().limit()];
            record.key().get(key);

            byte[] value = new byte[record.value().limit()];
            record.value().get(value);

            System.out.println("key : " + new String(key) + " value: " +  new String(value));
            return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<byte[], byte[]>(key, value);
        }else if(record.hasValue()){
            // illegal impl
            byte[] data = new byte[record.value().limit()];
            record.value().get(data);
            System.out.println("no key but with value : " + new String(data));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```